# Problems with hiding a customCell

Tags: swift, nsnotificationcenter

I have a custom cell with it's own class and I wanna set visibility of that cell by pushing a button in my main Viewcontroller but I don't know how to set the visibility in the class by pushing the button i know that i have to use notification sending but where do i write the code in the customcell class? Can anyone give me an example?
this is my code

viewController

```
   @IBAction func OpenAdd(_ sender: Any) {
        if(openAdd == false){
            openAdd = true
            tableView.reloadData()
        }else{
            openAdd = false
            tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }
```

customCell

```
import UIKit

class AddCell: UITableViewCell {



    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
```

Comment: Is the button outside the cell?

Comment: Yes the one that hides it is

Comment: If it's located outside the cell then how do you know which cell to hide? Could you share a screenshot?

Comment: Well there must be a way to get the cell in my vc

Comment: In your main view controller in the OpenAdd method, set a flag to show/hide the cell. Then reload the collection view and in cellForItemAt method check if indexpath is the right one, cell.isHiddent = true

Comment: If your table view has multiple cells, then in order to determine which cell you want to hide you can use UITableVieCell's tag property. You can set it in 'cellForRow' delegate function. Then you can get a reference to the proper cell by calling `cellForRow(at:)`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to use `layoutSubviews` if you want do some display changes

```
class AddCell: UITableViewCell {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // write your code here

    }
}
```

// In ViewController - 
This is optional . It may cause some errors when usage is wrong. I dont know your all staff.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!  {
        var cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("AddCell") as! AddCell

        cell.layoutSubviews()

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: The question here is quz i have one cell that will never become more then one which is custom then i have another cell that will be used all the time that doesn't have to do with this subject at all but the first one should be hidden at the start and then visible when you click the open add method